# How to call Firefox printpreview using addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to call Firefox printpreview using addon SDK.
Newest SDK (1.16) not include [printultis.js](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=fchWYA3kuH7sqRZ9BoZCj_W9crU&cid=4ESc7cIf2f0&s=&fp=305506&mp=&projSelected=true#L0)

Thank you somuch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');

var chromewin = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
chromewin.PrintUtils.printPreview(chromewin.PrintPreviewListener);
```

Comment: it's said ../main has no authority to load: sdk/window/utils

Comment: Content scripts are are barred from using the SDk APIs, `main.js` is ok. Try it yourself.

Comment: I write this in main.js. Just: const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');

Browser console warning /main has no authority to load: sdk/window/utils.
I use somuch library in my addon
const widgets = require("sdk/widget");
const data = require("sdk/self").data;
var preferences =  require("sdk/preferences/service");
preferences.set("print.save_print_settings",true);   
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome"); 
var { Hotkey } = require("sdk/hotkeys");
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');;//this line return bug

Comment: Please send to me your email address. I will send for you my addon package. You saved my life. Thank you so much.

Comment: Upvoting and accepting the answer is more than enough reward. Did you find what caused the `no authority to load` message?

Comment: i dont have 15 reputation to vote up for you, i was accepted your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
const BROWSER = 'navigator:browser' ; 
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome"); 
const WM = Cc['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1'].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);
function getMostRecentBrowserWindow() {
return getMostRecentWindow(BROWSER);
}
exports.getMostRecentBrowserWindow = getMostRecentBrowserWindow;  
function getMostRecentWindow(type) {
return WM.getMostRecentWindow(type);
}
exports.getMostRecentWindow = getMostRecentWindow;
var chromewin = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
chromewin.PrintUtils.printPreview(chromewin.PrintPreviewListener);
```

This worked