# has no authority to load: sdk/window/utils (Firefox addon SDK)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my Main.js

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var chromewin = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
chromewin.PrintUtils.printPreview(chromewin.PrintPreviewListener);
```

Browser console warning: "Module: .../main has no authority to load: sdk/window/utils"

Comment: Look inside the xpi (generated with `cfx xpi`), does `harness-options.json` contain the line `"sdk/window/utils": "sdk/window/utils"`?

Comment: Paa, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703545/how-to-call-firefox-printpreview-using-addon-sdk?sfb=2.

Comment: Still, it's a mystery to be solved :)

Comment: sure, i looked in util.js. They call so much services: appShellService,window-watcher,io-service and sdk/core/promise. Exactly promise.js return bug "has no authority to load: sdk/window/utils". I think reason is permission of window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your addon contains a corrupted or otherwise incomplete `harness-options.json`. Either rebuild your addon with a fresh copy of Addon SDK, or (more tricky) manually edit `harness-options.json` so that under the `requirements` section all `require`d modules are listed.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I would try this instead:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
getMostRecentBrowserWindow().PrintUtils.printPreview(getMostRecentBrowserWindow().PrintPreviewListener);
```

My guess is that you are trying to use your `chromewin` ref after that window has closed.

Comment: If that was the issue, a different error would appear. To me it seems like a build problem. For some reason `sdk/window/utils` is not included in the `requirements` section of the manifest.